# Entity framework return items from list that not contained in a table

Tags: entity-framework, list, contains

I am new using entity framework
i have a list of form numbers and i want to search from a table for that list of  form numbers and then return form numbers from the list that not contains in the table 
i tried this query it gave me half of the work:

here is my list:

```
var strPurchaseFormNoList= new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" }
```

and this is my query:

```
    var checkPurchaseAccount = vcEntities.VcUserAccountTbls.Where(x =>
 !strPurchaseFormNoList.Contains(x.FormNo))
```

how to select form numbers in the list that not include from the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for the "Except" extension.

```
var reject_list= vcEntities.VcUserAccountTbls.Where(p =>strPurchaseFormNoList.Contains(p.FormNo))
var checkPurchaseAccount = vcEntities.VcUserAccountTbls.Except(reject_list);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying so we couldn't use one query to do that ?

Comment: I tried your solution but it returns the form number that includes from the table and not in the list i want opposite returning from the list not in the table.